# how to click with selenium in python onclick without class, id or name

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I'm trying to find a way to click on "X" button but I cannot find the way to click on this button.

Element copy:

```
<div style="cursor: pointer; float:right; border-radius: 3px; background-color: red; font-size: 10px; color: white; height: 15px; width:15px; line-height: 15px;" onclick="fecharModal();">X</div>
```

Xpath:

```
//*[@id="meu_modal"]/div
```

Css Selector:

```
#meu_modal > div
```

Tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onclick*=fecharModal]").click();
```

Imports:

> from selenium import webdriver from selenium.webdriver.common.keys
> import Keys from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select from
> selenium.webdriver.common.by import By from
> selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait from
> selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC from
> selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException from
> selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains import
> time`enter code here`

Comment: have you tried
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="meu_modal"]/div").click()`

Comment: Hi @Huzaifa, yes, I had tried your suggestion and the error - "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='meu_modal']/div"}
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.82)

Comment: I also had tried.

#tried1: WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='meu_modal']"))).click()
#tried2: WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@name='x']"))).click()
#tried3: WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='onclick']"))).click()

Comment: Does the Element get highlighted when you put that xpath in the DOM. If yes, check if the element is in an `iframe`.

Comment: The markup is a div, but you tried to select an anchor tag.

Comment: Also add quotes to your selector. Try this div[onclick*='fecharModal']

Comment: Can you give the link of website?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an angular bases application, mostly `WebDriverWait` should do the job, but still below solution `illustarte` all the ways in **Selenium** to click a **web element.** **Code trial 2** is more preferable and best practices.

I will use this xpath

```
//div[@onclick='fecharModal();' and text()='X']
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@onclick='fecharModal();' and text()='X']").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@onclick='fecharModal();' and text()='X']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@onclick='fecharModal();' and text()='X']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@onclick='fecharModal();' and text()='X']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Comment: Hi @Cruisepandey, thank you for your time to slipt out this explanations. In fact still didn't work. 
Code1: NoSuchElementException
Code2:  "TimeoutException: Message: "
Code3: NoSuchElementException
Code4: NoSuchElementException
I had followed the "Step to check" that you had mentioned about xpath and  the result get highlighted 1/1. I think that is almost there. haha

Comment: @user16792636 : I am pretty much sure either it is in iframe or not in selenium view port. Please check for iframe, and let me know if it is in iframe

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that the xpath you provided is accurate, I suggest you try this code possibly this might work for you.

```
yourEle = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='meu_modal']/div")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", yourEle)
```

Comment: And if needed add some wait or Thread sleep.

Comment: Hi @enthusiasticCoder, I had tried your suggestion but unfortunately . didn't work. 
message error: "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:"